# Please explain this structure and why it's used like this?

Tags: android, email

I found the code segment below in [this tutorial][1]. I don't understand what exactly happens. It seems like the button is created and that a listener is then set to listen for when it's clicked, but why is the entire `onClick(View view)` method inside the (...) of the `sendMail.setOnClickListener()`?

Regarding `setOnClickListener`, Eclipse said:

> Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this view is not clickable, it becomes clickable.

So am I correct in saying that the structure is as it is to almost simultaneously see if the button is clickable, make it clickable if it isn't and create a listener for the button?

But I still don't understand why it was written and structured like this:

```
Button sendMail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email); 
    sendMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        public void onClick(View view) { 
          Mail m = new Mail("email@gmail.com", "password");     

          m.setTo("email@gmail.com"); 
          m.setFrom("email@gmail.com"); 
          m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
          m.setBody("Email body."); 

          try { 
            m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

            if(m.send()) { 

            Toast.makeText(m, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    

            } else { 
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
          } catch(Exception e) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
          } 
        } 
      });
```

In my mind it should be:

```
sendMail.setOnClickListener();
sendMail.onClick(this);

public void onClick(View view) {...}
```

Any comments or Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this view is not clickable, it becomes clickable.

Comment: The link to the tutorial seems missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a subclass. This method is known as anonymous subclassing. It allows to you to create a subclass and use it together.

Anonymous subclass do not have constructors as the class has no name. For that you need to use instance initialisers. Basically these classes are used when creating another class file for it feels redundant and if you want to keep the class code together in the same block(Atleast that why i use it for).

Answer (score 2):

It is called an anonymous class. Instead of creating a new class with the `class` keyword, you just use the syntax `new <superclass-or-interface-name>() { ... }` with all the required methods.

Read more about anonymous classes at [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Nested_Classes#Anonymous_Classes)

Answer (score 2):

It's called an anonymous inner class, its a common Java pattern.  You are free to define an explicit class that implements the method and set your listener to it, instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how it works when you create a new instance of the `Listener` inside the `setOnClickListener()` method. Nothing weird about that at all.

Alternatively, you can set a method for `android:onClick` in the button XML side. In code, you'll need to do the following:

```
public void testMethod(View v) {
  // code
}
```